# Navbar submenus dropdown opened by default

Tags: html, css, bulma

I'm trying to implement a navbar megamenu on my website using Bulma, since is the only framework that I found that works without interfering with the code already on the website. I never used Bulma before, and have only some basic knowledge of CSS, HTML and PHP.

The navbar is working fine on the desktop version, but I'm stuck on the mobile version. The drop-down menus are expanded by default, and I can't figure it out how to disable this behaviour. This is my code:

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://res.cloudinary.com/rosaritoliving/raw/upload/v1564503077/Baja123%20Menu/megamenu_1564427792.css">
            <script>
            .navbar-item.is-mega {
            position: static;
            .is-mega-menu-title {
            margin-bottom: 0;
            padding: .375rem 1rem;
            }
            }
            </script>
            </head>
            <body>
            <nav class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-brand">
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com">
            <img src="https://mlvtslglmiuu.i.optimole.com/otn1P_eJnbI/w:461/h:92/q:auto/https://www.rosaritoliving.com/wp-content/uploads/logo-baja123-real-estate.png" alt="Baja123 Baja's Best Real Estate Website" width="150" height="50">
            </a>
            <div class="navbar-burger burger" data-target="navMenubd-example">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div id="navMenubd-example" class="navbar-menu">
            <div class="navbar-start">
            <div class="navbar-item">
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com">HOME</a></div>
            <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable is-boxed">
            <div class="navbar-link">OCEANFRONT LISTINGS
            </div>
            <div id="moreDropdown" class="navbar-dropdown is-boxed">
            <div class="container">
            <div class="columns">
            <div class="column">
            <h1 class="title is-6 is-mega-menu-title has-text-danger has-text-weight-bold">BAJA REAL ESTATE</h1>
            <div class="navbar-content">
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/BAJA_REAL_ESTATE/page_2493056.html">Listings for Sale</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/ROSARITO_BEACH_AREA_RENTALS/page_1666562.html">Listings for Rent</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/BAJA_LIVING/page_2312494.html">About Baja California</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            <h1 class="title is-6 is-mega-menu-title has-text-danger has-text-weight-bold">ROSARITO REAL ESTATE</h1>
            <div class="navbar-content">
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/ROSARITO_REAL_ESTATE/page_1754239.html">Listings for Sale</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/ROSARITO_BEACH_AREA_RENTALS/page_1666562.html">Listings for Rent</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/ROSARITO_ROSARITO_MAIN_PAGE_BUYERS_GUIDE/page_2615332.html">About Rosarito Beach</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            <h1 class="title is-6 is-mega-menu-title has-text-danger has-text-weight-bold">TIJUANA REAL ESTATE</h1>
            <div class="navbar-content">
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/TIJUANA_REAL_ESTATE_LISTINGS/page_1754238.html">Listings for Sale</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/ROSARITO_BEACH_AREA_RENTALS/page_1666562.html">Listings for Rent</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/TIJUANA_BUYERS_GUIDE/page_2649211.html">About Tijuana</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            <h1 class="title is-6 is-mega-menu-title has-text-danger has-text-weight-bold">ENSENADA REAL ESTATE</h1>
            <div class="navbar-content">
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/ENSENADA_REAL_ESTATE_LISTINGS/page_1754240.html">Listings for Sale</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/ROSARITO_BEACH_AREA_RENTALS/page_1666562.html">Listings for Rent</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/ENSENADA_BUYERS_GUIDE/page_2650491.html">About Ensenada</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable is-boxed">
            <div class="navbar-link">BAJA LIVING</div>
            <div id="blogDropdown" class="navbar-dropdown is-boxed">
            <div class="container">
            <div class="columns">
            <div class="column">
            <h1 class="title is-6 is-mega-menu-title has-text-danger has-text-weight-bold">UTILITIES AND SERVICES</h1>
            <div class="navbar-content">
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/UTILITIES_AND_SERVICES_IN_BAJA_Water_Company/page_2312474.html">Water Company</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/UTILITIES_AND_SERVICES_IN_BAJA_Electric_Company/page_2522445.html">Electric Company</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/UTILITIES_AND_SERVICES_IN_BAJA_Gas_Company/page_2522339.html">Gas Company</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/UTILITIES_AND_SERVICES_IN_BAJA_Telephone_Service/page_2313221.html">Telephone Service</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/UTILITIES_AND_SERVICES_IN_BAJA_Internet_Service/page_2313224.html">Internet Service</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/UTILITIES_AND_SERVICES_IN_BAJA_Cellular_Service/page_2313222.html">Cellular Service</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/UTILITIES_AND_SERVICES_IN_BAJA_Television_Service/page_2313223.html">TV Service</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/UTILITIES_AND_SERVICES_IN_BAJA_How_to_Dial_Phones/page_2313225.html">How to Dial Phones in Mexico</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/UTILITIES_AND_SERVICES_IN_BAJA_Emergency_Numbers/page_2522342.html">Emergency Phone Numbers</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/UTILITIES_AND_SERVICES_IN_BAJA_Bill_Paying_Service/page_2522340.html">Bill Paying Services</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            <h1 class="title is-6 is-mega-menu-title has-text-danger has-text-weight-bold">MOVING YOUR FURNITURE TO THE ROSARITO AREA</h1>
            <div class="navbar-content">
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/MOVING_YOUR_PERSONAL_PROPERTY_INTO_MEXICO/page_2313227.html">Moving Instructions</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/STORAGE_SERVICES_IN_THE_ROSARITO_BEACH_AREA/page_2645216.html">Storage Options</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/MOVING_SERVICES_IN_THE_ROSARITO_BEACH_AREA/page_2645197.html">Moving Services</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            <h1 class="title is-6 is-mega-menu-title has-text-danger has-text-weight-bold">AUTO INFORMATION</h1>
            <div class="navbar-content">
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/DRIVING_A_US_VEHICLE_IN_MEXICO/page_2313790.html">Driving your Car in Baja</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/DRIVING_TIPS_AND_RULES_FOR_MEXICO/page_2313786.html">Driving Tips and Information</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/AUTOMOBILE_INSURANCE_IN_MEXICO/page_2313289.html">Auto Insurancce Services</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/MECHANICS_IN_THE_ROSARITO_BEACH_AREA/page_2313784.html">Auto Repair Services</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            <h1 class="title is-6 is-mega-menu-title has-text-danger has-text-weight-bold">HEALTH CARE, HOSPITALS AND DOCTORS IN THE ROSARITO AREA</h1>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/HEALTHCARE_DOCTORS_DENTISTS_AND_HOSPITALS/page_2054379.html">Healthcare, Doctors, Dentists and Hospitals</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="navbar-divider">
            <div class="columns">
            <div class="column">
            <h1 class="title is-6 is-mega-menu-title has-text-danger has-text-weight-bold">INSURANCE SERVICES IN BAJA</h1>
            <div class="navbar-content">
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/AUTOMOBILE_INSURANCE_IN_MEXICO/page_2313289.html">Auto Insurance Services</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/MEDICAL_INSURANCE_IN_MEXICO/page_2313292.html">Medical Insurance Services</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/HOMEOWNER_INSURANCE_IN_MEXICO/page_2313290.html">Homeowners Insurance Services</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            <h1 class="title is-6 is-mega-menu-title has-text-danger has-text-weight-bold">PETS AND VETS</h1>
            <div class="navbar-content">
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/MOVING_PETS_INTO_MEXICO/page_2058791.html">Bring your Pet to the Rosarito Area</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            <h1 class="title is-6 is-mega-menu-title has-text-danger has-text-weight-bold">PROFESSIONAL SERVICES IN BAJA</h1>
            <div class="navbar-content">
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/IMMIGRATION_SERVICES_IN_THE_ROSARITO_BEACH_AREA/page_1681440.html">Immigration Services</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/MAIL_SERVICE_IN_ROSARITO_BEACH/page_2522113.html">Mail Services</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/UTILITIES_AND_SERVICES_IN_BAJA_Bill_Paying_Service/page_2522340.html">Bill Paying Services</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/LEGAL_SERVICES_IN_MEXICO/page_2313260.html">Legal Services</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/ACCOUNTING_IN_MEXICO/page_2313261.html">Accounting Services</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/STORAGE_SERVICES_IN_THE_ROSARITO_BEACH_AREA/page_2645216.html">Storage Services</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/MOVING_SERVICES_IN_THE_ROSARITO_BEACH_AREA/page_2645197.html">Moving Services</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/CLOSING_SERVICES_FOR_BAJA_REAL_ESTATE/page_2645211.html">Closing Services</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/PROPERTY_MANAGEMENT_IN_MEXICO/page_2313213.html">Property Management</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            <h1 class="title is-6 is-mega-menu-title has-text-danger has-text-weight-bold">TRANSPORTATION SERVICES</h1>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/GETTING_AROUND_IN_THE_ROSARITO_BEACH_AREA/page_2313801.html">Transportation in Rosarito Beach</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="navbar-divider">
            <div class="column">
            <h1 class="title is-6 is-mega-menu-title has-text-danger has-text-weight-bold">SHOPPING IN THE ROSARITO AREA</h1>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/BUYING_FOOD_IN_MEXICO/page_2313807.html">Supermarkets & Convenience Stores</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/BUYING_HOUSEHOLD_FURNISHINGS_IN_MEXICO/page_2313809.html">Furniture & Appliances</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            <div class="navbar-content">
            <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable is-boxed">
            <div class="navbar-link">
            SELLERS & BUYERS
            </div>
            <div id="moreDropdown" class="navbar-dropdown is-boxed">
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/BAJA_REAL_ESTATE/page_2493056.html">
            <div class="level is-mobile">
            <div class="level-left">
            <div class="level-item">
            <p>
            <strong>Baja Real Estate</strong>
            <br>
            <small>Click Here!</small>
            </p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="level-right">
            <div class="level-item">
            <span class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-search "></i>
            </span>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/LIST_YOUR_ROSARITO_BEACH_PROPERTY/page_2198558.html">
            <div class="level is-mobile">
            <div class="level-left">
            <div class="level-item">
            <p>
            <strong>List Your Property</strong>
            <br>
            <small>Click Here!</small>
            </p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="level-right">
            <div class="level-item">
            <span class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-usd"></i>
            </span>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/Newsletter/page_2517204.html">
            <div class="level is-mobile">
            <div class="level-left">
            <div class="level-item">
            <p>
            <strong>Hot Property Alert</strong>
            <br>
            <small>Click Here!</small>
            </p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="level-right">
            <div class="level-item">
            <span class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
            </span>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/MEXICO_BUYERS_GUIDE/page_2609247.html">
            <div class="level is-mobile">
            <div class="level-left">
            <div class="level-item">
            <p>
            <strong>Buyer's Guide</strong>
            <br>
            <small>Click Here!</small>
            </p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="level-right">
            <div class="level-item">
            <span class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-compass"></i>
            </span>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </a>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-item">
            <a class="navbar-item" href="http://blog.baja123.com/" target="_blank">BLOG</a></div>
            <div class="navbar-item">
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.baja123.com/CONTACT_US/page_1232095.html">CONTACT US</a></div>
            </nav>
            </body>
            </html>
            <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            // Get all "navbar-burger" elements
            var $navbarBurgers = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-burger'), 0);
            // Check if there are any nav burgers
            if ($navbarBurgers.length > 0) {
            // Add a click event on each of them
            $navbarBurgers.forEach(function ($el) {
            $el.addEventListener('click', function () {
            // Get the target from the "data-target" attribute
            var target = $el.dataset.target;
            var $target = document.getElementById(target);
            // Toggle the class on both the "navbar-burger" and the "navbar-menu"
            $el.classList.toggle('is-active');
            $target.classList.toggle('is-active');
            });
            });
            }
            });</script>
```

I need the dropdown menus to be collapsed by default on the mobile version, right now they are expanded by default. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please add a link to your page or create a Minimal Reproducible example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ?

Comment: [link] (https://www.rosaritofix.com/test.html)
@NataliaDavydova